# Is it possible to embed Netsuite forms on the website?

Tags: netsuite

I want to embed Netsuite forms on the website. I want to embed a contact form. I searched a lot but couldn't find any resources other than [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Netsuite/comments/5rp20f/externally_embed_netsuite_forms_on_wordpress/).

Is it possible to embed Netsuite forms on our website? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

- You create a Suitlet accessible with an external link
- You use code or no code tool to create a form and send the information with the Netsuite API

Comment: Yes, I believe API is the only way to achieve this.